# Why is it possible to run Go tests and builds inside CI environments without having to install the dependencies first?

Tags: go, github-actions

I have a Go project with a Makefile

```
test:
    @go test -cover ./...
```

and a mod file

```
module path/to/repo

go 1.19

require github.com/go-chi/chi/v5 v5.0.8
```

I created a Github action sample to run tests on a Github PR

```
name: QA on pull request

on: pull_request

jobs:
  run-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: 1.19

      - name: Run tests
        run: make test
```

I would like to know why this workflow is working without a `install dependencies` step. The project itself is using external dependencies and I think there should be a step that runs `go get ./...`

Does Go install them under the hood if not present? Or does the action `actions/setup-go@v3` install the dependencies?

Comment: It's hard to say anything without any information about those deps. You need to include those in your question. Apart from that, the GitHub Actions runners already have [preinstalled software](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software). You might want to look at those also e.g. `ubuntu-latest` in your case.

Comment: Thanks! You should also check the logs to verify the installation of deps during CI.

Comment: Compiling Go code (including the tests) doesn't need any "installation" of "dependencies" as it might be common in other languages. There _are_ dependencies but these are not "installed" on your system. They are just managed by the go tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`go test`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/test) docs (or you may run `go help test` locally to read its description):

> 'Go test' recompiles each package along with any files with names matching the file pattern "*_test.go".

It also installs all the dependencies; so, it happens when the action does `go test`. You can probably observe it in the logs.

`actions/setup-go@v3` doesn't depend on the code itself. It just sets up the `go` environment you ask for. In your setup, if you swap the `setup-go` and `checkout`, it still works.

Comment: You might want to link to https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/test and quote the relevant part in your answer.